# html attribute correct (in terms of standard)?

Tags: html, css

I have found this odd (for me) syntax in the source of a website:

```
<td style></td>
```

Should an attribute be placed and not defined in an html element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK WebKit will erase everything that is passed in `"` when displaying source when nothing is passed.

Example: `<div style=""></div>` will become `<div style></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

It's legal [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2): "Elements *may* [my emphasis] have associated properties, called attributes, which may have values (by default, or set by authors or scripts)."

Answer (score 1):

In practice, if `style` alone is used as an attribute, it is ignored—except when an XHTML document is served with an XML content type, in which case it constitutes a well-formedness error, and the document is not displayed at all, and an error message is shown.

In principle, it depends on HTML version. By existing specifications, it is an error. HTML5 is vague about this, or I can’t find the place where this is discussed there, but the W3C HTML Validator in HTML5 mode accepts.